# Hive query is giving error

Tags: hive

I have a HIVE table called testdata and the columns are as follows

1. name
2. age
3. gender

From hive prompt when i am issuing the command "select * from testdata", it is showing me the whole dataset. But when i am issuing the command select name from testdata, it is showing me the error

java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No Route to Host from [NAMENODE_IP] to [CLUSTER_IP]:35946 failed on socket timeout exception: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/NoRouteToHost.

Can anybody please help me to find out what exactly i am doing wrong.

My Hadoop Version is 2.2.0 and Hive version is 0.11.0

Answer (score 1):

Check for your 'hosts' file, system's current IP should have to be first entry in your hosts file.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same trouble so I thought I would tell you guys what I did to fix this very issue.

1) Disable your firewall on the name node and see if it works

2) If it does then your firewall is blocking the network discussions between nodes. You will have to manually add rules to allow connections between your name node IPs

You can find how to do so with this very detailed answer on iptables here
https://serverfault.com/questions/30026/whitelist-allowed-ips-in-out-using-iptables/30031#30031

Answer (score 0):

You need correct related hadoop configuration. It seems that hive cannot connect jobtracker.

When you query `select * from testdata` , hive have not use mapreduce to get result.

While you query `select name from testdata`, hive will call hadoop to start a mapreduce job.

So, make your hadoop configuration correct.